# C++: How to prevent default constructor using AVX for initialisation

Tags: c++, constructor, x86, sse, avx

Consider the following:

```
// foo.h
class Foo
{
   public:
      int x = 2;
      int y = 3;
      void DoSomething_SSE();
      void DoSomething_AVX();
   // ( Implicit default constructor is generated "inline" here )
};

// Foo_AVX.cpp, compiled with -mavx or /arch:AVX
void Foo::DoSomething_AVX()
{
   // AVX optimised implementation here
}

// Foo_SSE.cpp, compiled with -msse2 or /arch:SSE2
void Foo::DoSomething_SSE()
{
   // SSE optimised implementation here
}
```

Here's the problem: the compiler will generate the implied default constructor with 'inline' semantics (note: inline semantics does *not* mean the function will necessarily be inlined) in each translation unit, and - in cases where the constructor is not inlined - the linker will then choose one implementation and discard the other.

If the linker chooses the constructor generated in the AVX compilation unit, this code will then crash with an illegal instruction on a machine which doesn't support AVX.

It is possible to stop the crash by putting in an explicit default constructor, either __forceinline (to make sure it's inlined once per compilation unit), or declared in the header and defined in a compilation unit which is compiled with the lowest common denominator instruction set.

However, surely there's a way to get the language to handle this better than having to write dummy functions..?

(llvm-clang++ 9.x.x/x64 on Mac OS X)

Comment: Have you looked at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Function-Multiversioning.html or https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html? Don't know if it works for constructors though.

Comment: Why do you link code compiled for different architectures into the same binary!?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning

Comment: Dan M.: That would work in the simple case outlined above - however it's not possible AFAICT to tag template-instantiations (for example) with function attributes.

Comment: Michael Kenzel: Have been doing this fine for some years - they're the same underlying architecture (x64) but different cpu feature sets, so that one executable can run optimised on different generations of processor - SSE2, SSE4, AVX, AVX2, AVX512. Only when I began to rely more heavily on default constructors did it become a problem.

Comment: Calling an `SSE` generated constructor from code which otherwise uses `AVX` is not good either. One pragmatic solution to this would be to compile/link different binaries for different architectures and have a small dispatcher binary which just calls the binary corresponding to the current architecture. 

Btw, use `@Name` instead of `Name: ` so people get notifications if you answer them.

Comment: @chtz: with optimization enabled, the default constructor will simply inline, unless it's very big because of a lot of different default-initialized member variables.  Plus, every non-inline function call has to be made in `vzeroupper` state anyway unless it takes an `__m256` arg.  This can't result in SSE/AVX transition penalties.  It might stop link-time optimization from inlining, but that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Compile the AVX Translation units with gcc or clang `-mavx -fno-implement-inlines`; the linker will have to find the symbol from the SSE translation units if the functions don't simply inline.

---

From the GCC manual:

> `-fno-implement-inlines`
>        To save space, do not emit out-of-line copies of inline functions controlled by `#pragma implementation`.  This causes linker errors if
>        these functions are not inlined everywhere they are called.

Clang supports this option, too.

This does *not* disable inlining of anything, it only disables emitting a stand-alone definition of functions declared as `inline` or in a class definition.

With optimization enabled, a small default constructor like in the question should inline (and use the target ISA options of the current function/compilation unit), making this irrelevant most of the time.  But it will make sure that un-optimized builds work properly on non-AVX machines.

Comment: Thank you very much, that will do the trick. Another solution which I found with much digging around is outlined below.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that another option is to not use compiler flags to set the instruction set - leave them on the default, and wrap only the functions which require the enhanced instruction set:

```
#include Foo.h

// Switch on AVX optimisations for the function where they're needed
#pragma clang attribute push (__attribute__((target("arch=sandybridge"))), apply_to = function)

void Foo::DoSomething_AVX()
{
   // AVX optimised implementation here
}
#pragma clang attribute pop
```

Using #pragma clang attribute push(...), while a bit more long-winded than simple `[[]]` or `__attribute__(())`, seems to have the advantage that the attribute is automatically applied to any template code etc. instantiated from within the pragma's scope.

Comment: Anything inlined into a function marked with `__attribute__((target(arch=sandybridge)))` will use the same code-gen.  Instantiating templates that *don't* inline with AVX code-gen might be dangerous if non-AVX code could also use those stand-alone functions.  Interesting idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the implementation into a separate .cpp file and voila everything works. 
The other way is to make those functions/methods/constructors inline. 
The third way (compiler dependent) is to set them a 'weak reference' attribute.

Comment: Missing the point: there **is** no implementation. These are defaulted functions.